# Convert to negative integer by reading characters

Tags: c, character-encoding, while-loop

This is a program which reads data character by character until it finds a character digit and converts it into an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  char ch = getchar();
  printf("Type some data including a number");
  while(ch < '0' || ch > '9') //as long as the character is not a digit.
  {
    ch = getchar();
  }

  int num = 0;
  while(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') //as long as we get a digit
  {
    num = num * 10 + ch - '0'; //convert char digit to integer
    ch = getchar();
  }
  printf("Number is %d\n",num);

}
```

This program only finds positive integers. I want the program to find negative integers aswell or floating point number. How do i make the program to do that? I tried using if statement inside the while loop that looks for a digit but that didnt work for me.

Comment: First, fix your indentation. Second, your first "while," that skips over non-numeric characters, will need to be instructed not to skip '-' and '.'. And then you will have to handle the case where you run into a '-' or a '.' but it is not followed by digits and thus is not part of a number.

Comment: I don't understand, first you say you want to convert char into digits and then you say that you want the program to find negative integers ???

Comment: Normally, you emit the prompt before reading the first character.  In fact, idiomatic C would use: `int c; printf("..."); while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && (c < '0' || c > '9')) ;` (where the trailing semicolon would be on a line of its own).  Extending that to handle +3.14E-13 is non-trivial; you probably need a state machine of some sort (or use `scanf()` or one of its relatives).

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though `fscanf` will be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

E.g

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    //input format ([^0-9]*-)?[0-9]+

    int ch, sign = 1;
    while(!isdigit(ch=getchar())){
        if(ch=='-'){
            ch=getchar();//one character look-ahead
            if(isdigit(ch)){
                sign = -1;
            }
            ungetc(ch, stdin);//push back
        }
    }

    int num;
    for(num=0;isdigit(ch);ch = getchar()){
        num = num * 10 + ch - '0';
    }
    num *= sign;

    printf("Number is %d\n",num);

    return 0;
}
```